# add scrolling arrows to presentation (to switch between slides)

Tags: beamer, pdf, overleaf, presentations, bar

how can i add scroll arrows to slides latex.
to switch slides in pdf.
i'm using overleaf beamer .
thank you for helping .

that
that it completely describes my problem it completely describes my problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I suppose that the default `beamer` already provides that at the southeast corner?

Answer (score 2):

Beamer comes with navigation symbols by default. To switch to the next/previous slide, click on these icons at the bottom

[image]

If for some reason your theme removes these icons, you can add them back with

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}[horizontal]
```